# Raspberry 3B+ fails to playback video stream

Tags: video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, vlc

I'm trying to set up a Raspberry 3b+ as a playback device for a projector. But nevertheless what I try on the raspberry I can't get the video playback running smoothly. The stream is coming from OBS as mpegts Stream (video encoded with libx264 8000kbps with a keyframe every 125 frames. Audio is currently encoded as opus stream).

As long as I only stream a steady image with no movement the playback is more or less fine (audio playback without stutter).
But when I stream for example a movie the image freezes and also the sound stutters.

The video memory of the Raspi is set to 256MB.

Nevertheless what I try I don't get it working.

Edit:
When I start VLC on my arch linux system it plays the stream smoothly.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ vlc play.xspf 
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
[00c9bb58] main libvlc: VLC wird mit dem Standard-Interface ausgeführt. Benutzen Sie 'cvlc', um VLC ohne Interface zu verwenden.
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
qt5ct: D-Bus global menu: no
qt5ct: D-Bus system tray: no
[55ff70c8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: Legacy
[55ff6030] udp stream error: 1472 bytes packet truncated (MTU was 1316)
[55ff70c8] mmal_codec decoder: VCSM init succeeded: Legacy
[55ff70c8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 4096
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
[5f10b7a8] mmal_xsplitter vout display error: Failed to open Xsplitter:opengles2 module
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 7) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 7) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 13, expected 11) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 13, expected 11) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 15) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 15) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 5) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 5) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 8) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 8) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 5, expected 4) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 5, expected 4) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 12, expected 11) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 12, expected 11) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 8) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 8) for PID 4096
[00d43cd8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 1000 ms)
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 12) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 9, expected 12) for PID 4096
[55ff70c8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 13, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 13, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 7) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 8, expected 7) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 8, expected 7) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 5, expected 4) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 3, expected 2) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 3, expected 2) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 14) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 14, expected 13) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 1) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 5) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 5) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 10, expected 9) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 10, expected 9) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 12, expected 11) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 12, expected 11) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 1, expected 0) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 10, expected 9) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 10, expected 9) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 12) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 15, expected 12) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 3, expected 2) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 3, expected 2) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 4) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 6, expected 4) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 7) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 7) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 15) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 2, expected 15) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 11, expected 10) for PID 17
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 7, expected 6) for PID 4096
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 0
[55c29ca8] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 0, expected 15) for PID 4096
^CQObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Comment: can you share some logs please?

Comment: I edited the question and added the log file.